# Как вставить картинку в QLabel, чтобы она не растягивалась на всю площадь, а сохраняла пропорции?

Tags: c++, qt, label, qss

Вставляю картинку так:

```
ui->label->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(C:/Users/Meshtli/Desktop/hi/Kursach/word/2.jpg);");
```

Comment: А если добавить `repeat` `"border-image: url(C:/Users/Meshtli/Desktop/hi/Kursach/word/2.jpg) repeat;"`?

Comment: а если просто `background-image:url(C:/Users/Meshtli/Desktop/hi/Kursach/word/2.jpg);`

Comment: Сорян, уже нашла решение. QPixmap p; // load pixmap
p.load("C:/Users/Meshtli/Desktop/hi/Kursach/word/2.jpg");
// get label dimensions
int w = ui->label->width();
int h = ui->label->height();

// set a scaled pixmap to a w x h window keeping its aspect ratio
ui->label->setPixmap(p.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));

Comment: @МарияМатвиенко, добавьте это решение в ответ :)